# Is there any way to whitelist sites to be recorded in PHP VCR

Tags: php-vcr

Is there any way I can whitelist the site for php-vcr to record?

```
VCR::configure()
   ->enableRequestMatchers(array([]));
```

There is a method called `enableRequestMatchers` but I dont think it does what I want to do.

The intention is only to record the response for a specific url.